# Social engine 4.2 installation steps

Tags: socialengine

I trying to install social engine and am facing problems. I am not able to find any good documentation on how to do this correctly. I have googled and yourtubed ...Please can anyone point me to some good step by step instructions on how to do this right.

thanks

Comment: If you are more specific about the problems you are facing, we might be able to help you

Answer (score 2):

Official SocialEngine Installation Tutorial - YouTube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-gUEzsesjU

You can find upgrade tutorial and more at SocialEngine:
http://www.youtube.com/user/socialenginetv